# Javascript Redirect window.location.href - IE

Tags: javascript

Trying to do a redirect with javascript using the following code (works fine in ALL browsers except IE8 and IE7):

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to clear your basket?')) {
    window.location.href = '/basket/clear';

    if (navigator.userAgent.search('MSIE') > -1) alert('Your basket has been cleared.');
}
```

I have added in the second alert stating that the basket has been cleared so that the code works in IE. If I remove the alert then it doesn't work.

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's coming from `href` of anchor tag you must also have `return false` otherwise the link will be "processed".

Comment: @Shadow Wizard This should be an answer. I, for one, think you are correct.

Comment: @Hemlock not sure that's the case here.. @ABailiss can you post the code invoking that JavaScript?

Comment: It was a button that called the code, not an anchor tag. Simply adding a return false; after the redirect seems to have fixed things in IE even though it is pointless returning false for a button.

Comment: what button exactly? If just plain `<button onclick="...">` it defaults to submit button that when clicked will submit its form. Anyway, when commenting on someone else comment use `@` to notify that person (one at a time) otherwise he/she won't see your comment.

Answer (score 3):

try using just `window.location = '/basket/clear';`

also, when you change the window location you cannot expect code beyond that point to execute, such as an `alert`

Comment: Removing the .href didn't work, the redirect only seems to work in IE when there is actually something after the redirect. I have simply added in return true; after the redirect and it now seems to work perfectly. Also, I changed window.location.href to top.location.href for consistency across the site that I am developing.

Comment: This also worked for an angularjs bug where `$window.location.href` didn't work for ie.  Thanks, Aleck